# Mocking a final class variable

Tags: unit-testing, junit4, powermockito

I am trying to test a class in which a final instance of class in used. I am not getting how to create a mock of this final object(in our example foo). After a lot of dig around I started using powermockito and whenNew method. I am not sure if I am doing it correctly or not as I am new to JUnits.
After looking at this I changed the `@PrepareForTest` to `Sample.class`(earlier it was `Foo.class`) and after that both foo and koo are coming null.

Class Foo

```java
public class Foo{
  void hello(){
  }
}
```

Class Sample

```java
public class Sample{
  private final Foo foo= new Foo();
  private Koo koo = new Koo();
  String run(){
    String strr = koo.something();
    return foo.hello();
  }
}
```

Test Class

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareWith({Sample.class})
public class SampleTest{
  @InjectMocks
  private Sample sample;

  @Mock
  private Koo koo;

  @Test
  void run(){
    Foo foo = PowerMockito.mock(Foo.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Foo.class).withNoArguments.thenReturn(foo);

    when(koo.something()).thenReturn("abc");
    when(foo.hello()).thenReturn("def");
    String check = sample.run();
    assertEquals("abc", check);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foo is an instance variable that will be initialized when Sample class is instantiated. If you want to mock this instance variable using *whenNew* then it should happen while the Sample class is loaded before the test method is executed.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Sample.class })
public class SampleTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private Sample sample;

  @BeforeClass 
  public static void setUp() throws Exception {

    Foo foo = PowerMockito.mock(Foo.class);
    Mockito.when(foo.hello()).thenReturn("def");
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Foo.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(foo);
  }

  @Test
  public void run() throws Exception {

    String check = sample.run();
    Assert.assertEquals("def", check);
  }
}
```